# Analysis of insertion sort on an array with interleaved 1s and 0s

Tags: algorithm, performance, insertion-sort, big-o

What is the number of compares to insertion sort an array of N/2 1s interleaved with N/2 0s (e.g., 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0) ? 
The key lies in counting the number of inversions. But I don't think I am counting them right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zero with `i` zeros before it has `n/2 - i` ones after it. The answer is

```
n/2-1             n/2
 sum  (n/2 - i) = sum j = (n/2 + 1) (n/2) / 2.
 i=0              j=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have `n*(n+2)/8` moves.

When you insert any `0` at position `i` you will have to move right `i/2` `1`s. Any `1` should already be in the correct position and thus not require any moves.